# Counts of each element in an array (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for an elegant (Javascript) way to reduce an array of elements, say `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'c']` into an object of the form

```js
{
  2: ['a', 'c'],
  1: ['b', 'd'],
}
```

i.e. that where the key is the number of occurences and the value is an array containing all the elements which occur that number of times.

I have so far only been able to find solutions for an object of the form

```js
{
  'a': 2,
  'b': 1,
  'c': 2,
  'd': 1
}
```

which isn't quite what I'm after.

I know that I could do something along the lines of the following, but it doesn't feel particularly elegant

```js
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'c'];
// remove the duplicates from the original array so I don't process them twice
const uniqueElements = new Set(array);
const countObject = {};

uniqueElements.forEach(e => {
  // count the number of times the element appears in the original array
  const elementCount = array.filter(a => a === e).length;
  // update the array in the countObject
  const currentElements = countObject[elementCount];
  currentElements.push(e);
  countObject[elementCount] = currentElements;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over the unique elements of the array, with an object to group all the elements with the same count.

```js
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'c'];
let res = [...new Set(arr)].reduce((acc, curr) => {
  (acc[arr.reduce((a, b) => a + (b === curr), 0)] ??= []).push(curr);
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) twice, to group on the amount, and then change it to the format you'd like:

```js
const data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'c'];

const reduces = data.reduce((p, c) => {
    p[c] = (p[c] || 0);
    p[c]++;
    return p;
}, {});

const result = Object.keys(reduces).reduce((p, k) => {
    let n = reduces[k];
    p[n] = (p[n] || []);
    p[n].push(k);
    return p;
}, {});

console.log(reduces);
console.log(result);
```

output:

```json
{
  "1": [
    "b",
    "d"
  ],
  "2": [
    "a",
    "c"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use two loops: one to count, one to distribute the letters per count:

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'c'];

const counter = {}, result = {};
for (const ch of arr) counter[ch] = counter[ch] + 1 || 1;
for (const ch in counter) (result[counter[ch]] ??= []).push(ch);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a `Map`, count the items and iterate the map for building the result object.

```js
const
    data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'c'],
    result = {};

data
    .reduce((m, v) => m.set(v, (m.get(v) || 0) + 1), new Map)
    .forEach((k, v) => (result[k] ??= []).push(v));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```